# Turtle-graphics onkey event not repeating

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, keyboard-events, python-turtle

I write this code to make a pong game. Everything works fine except for the left paddle.
When I press the buttons that control the movements and I keep them pressed, the paddles moves constantly until key release.
Except for the "w" key. This key makes the paddle move for just 1 step and then stops. If I want to move, I have to release and press again.
The onkey events uses the same function of the "down" button, so I assume it's correct.
I tried to change onkey with onkeypressed but it doesn't work.
Below is the code: the Paddle module contains Paddle, a class that inherits from the Turtle class, and the functions go_up and go_down.

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from paddle import Paddle

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.setup(width=800, height=600)
screen.title("Pong")
screen.tracer(0)

l_paddle = Paddle((-350, 0))
r_paddle = Paddle((350, 0))

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(r_paddle.go_up, "Up")
screen.onkey(r_paddle.go_down, "Down")
screen.onkey(l_paddle.go_up, "s")
screen.onkey(l_paddle.go_down, "w")

game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    screen.update()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: What happens if you put `screen.onkey(l_paddle.go_down, "w")` before `screen.onkey(l_paddle.go_up, "s")` ?

Comment: Same thing. I tried every position and every possible combination between the 4 buttons. I even tried to change "w" with another letter. Nothing changed. "s", "up" and "down" work correctly. Other buttons don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `screen.onkeypress()` instead of `screen.onkey()`; I had this issue before, and switching to `onkeypress()` solved it.

Comment: Alredy tried. Nothing happens. Thank you anyway